# Java; Pop and Push using two Queues

Tags: java, queue

So the assignment is to create a pop() and push(x) method using two queues. My code is as follows;

```
public class Queue {
    Node first;
    Node last;
    int N;
    
    public Queue() {
        first = null;
        last = null;
        N = 0;
    }
    
    class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        }
    
    public int add(int x) {
        Node u = new Node();
        u.data = x;
        u.next = first;
        first = u;
        if (N==0) {
            last =u;
        }
        N++;
        return x;
    }
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean isEmpty = false;
        if(N==0) {
            isEmpty = true;
        }
        return isEmpty;
    }
    
    public int remove(int i) {
        if (N==0) {
            return (Integer) null;
        }
        int x = first.data;
        if (--N == 0) {
            last = null;
        }
        N--;
        return x;
    }
    
    public void display() {
        Node current = first;
        
        if(first == null) {
            System.out.println("List is empty.");
        }
        System.out.print("Nodes: ");
        while(current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data+", ");
            current = current.next;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    public int size() {
        return N;
    }
}
```

And my Double Queue;

```
    public class DoubleQueue {
    // Creates 2 queues for the push and pop methods.
    static Queue q1 = new Queue();
    static Queue q2 = new Queue();

    // Push method.
    int push(int x) {
        Node u = q1.new Node(); // Creates new node.
        u.data = x; // Sets node to the value x.
        u.next = q1.first; // Places the new node at the head of the stack.
        q1.first = u; 
        if (q1.N==0) { // Checks if node is empty and adds it as tail if it is.
            q1.last = u;
        }
        q1.N++; // Increments the element counter.
        return x; 
        }
    
    // Pop method.
    static int pop() {
        // Sets variables.
        Node q1curr = q1.first;
        Node q1prev = null;
        Node q2curr = null;
        Node q2prev = null;
        int q1size = q1.size();
        int q2size;
        
        if (q1.N == 0) { // Checks if the queue is empty.
            return (Integer) null;
        }
        int x = q1.first.data; // Sets x to the head value.
        for(int i = 0; i <= q1.size(); i++) { // Loop to check entire queue.
            if (q1curr.data == x) { // If the data does not match x, it is added to the second queue.
                q1.remove(q1curr.data);
                q1curr = q1curr.next;
                System.out.print("q");
            }
            else { // If the data matches x, the counter is moved and the data is deleted.
                q2.add(q1curr.data);
                q1.remove(q1curr.data);
                q1curr = q1curr.next;
                System.out.println("x");
            }
        }
        
        q2curr = q2.first;
        q2size = q2.size();
        q1.display();
        q2.display();

        // Adds all the elements back into the first queue.
        for (int i = 0; i < q2.size(); i++) {
            if (q2curr != null) {
                q1.add(q2curr.data);
                q2curr = q1curr.next;
            }
        }
        
        return x; // Returns the value removed.
    }
}
```

And my Main;

```
    public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DoubleQueue dq = new DoubleQueue();
        dq.q1.add(1);
        dq.q1.add(2);
        dq.q1.add(3);
        dq.q1.add(4);
        dq.q1.add(5);
        dq.q1.display();
        dq.push(7);
        dq.q1.display();
        dq.pop();
        dq.q1.display();
    }

}
```

The issue I'm having is that during the pop method, originally I swapped q1 and q2, but q2 was in the reverse order. So instead, I tried to create a loop to add all the elements back. However, the loop will only iterate 2 times and then quit. I don't understand why my q1 is not removing the data each pass, or why the q2 only adds two of the nodes before quitting. Any advice on where I've gone wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: I apologize. I started java about two months ago, so I'm still learning all the proper conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to implement a stack using two queues. So I will suggest you rename the `DubbleQueue` class as `MyStack` or something else. I'm a bit confused about what you did in the `pop` function. I don't know why you pass the `val` in the `public int remove(int i)` function (actually don't use it at all). The `pop` function returns and removes the value from the first position. The value comparison shouldn't exist.

`MyQueye` class is like:
public class MyQueue {

```
static class Node {
    int val;
    Node next;

    public Node(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

private Node head = null, tail = null;
private int n = 0;

public boolean offer(int val) {
    Node node = new Node(val);
    if (null == head) {
        head = node;
    } else {
        tail.next = node;
    }
    tail = node;
    n ++;
    return true;
}

public int poll() {
    if (n <= 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
    int top = head.val;
    n --;
    head = head.next;
    if (n == 0) {
        tail = null;
    }
    return top;
}

public int size() {
    return n;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}}
```

`MyStack` class is like:

```
public class MyStack {

MyQueue in, out;

public MyStack() {
    in = new MyQueue();
    out = new MyQueue();
}

public int push(int val) {
    in.offer(val);
    while (!out.isEmpty()) {
        in.offer(out.poll());
    }
    swapInAndOut();
    return val;
}

public int pop() {
    if (out.isEmpty()) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    }
    return out.poll();
}

private void swapInAndOut() {
    MyQueue temp = in;
    in = out;
    out = temp;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyStack myStack = new MyStack();
    myStack.push(1);
    myStack.push(2);
    myStack.push(3);
    System.out.println(myStack.pop());
    System.out.println(myStack.pop());
    myStack.push(4);
    System.out.println(myStack.pop());
    System.out.println(myStack.pop());
}
```

}